# The endofayah symbol of the Uthmanic font in Android 13

Tags: android, fonts, arabic, android-13

When we write Arabic numbers in the Uthmanic font, it replaces the endofayah unicode with that number.

It works good on androids 6 to 12, but in android 13, the numbers are reversed. For example, when i write number 15 with Arabic numbers, it writes endofayah with number 51.

What should I change in the ligatures to fix the problem?